# How to organize Angular data service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have become slightly confused over Observables, Observers, Subjects, BehaviorSubjects, Services, injections, etc.

I am trying to make a simple finance app. I have a transactions service that grabs the data from a REST server and then provides it to other services that can update it if they need to. I can get the list transactions component (which gets its data from `getTransactions()`)to update with the service, but I don't know how to get the edit component (which gets its data from "`getTransaction(id)`" to work.

What is the best way to let components play with data from the entire array (read/write access) as well as those that just want to play with a single element of the array?

Here's what I have right now: (I've changed it a ton so it's currently broken, but you can see what I was doing)

```
export class DataBrokerService {
  public transactions:Transaction[];

  constructor() {}

   ngOnInit(){
   }

  getTransactions(): Observable<Transaction[]>{
    if (needUpdate){
      // Download from REST API, subscribe result to transactions
      this.updateTransactions();
    }
    return of(this.transactions);
  }

  getTransaction(id:number): Observable <Transaction>{
    let transaction:Transaction;
    this.getTransactions().subscribe(txns => transaction = txns.find(txn => txn.id === id))
    });
    return transaction$;
  }
```

I also made this demo showcasing what I am going for:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-demo-dftmn3

This is a followup question from: [Get one value from observable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454205/get-one-value-from-observable-array/50454344?noredirect=1#comment87925306_50454344)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused - getting certain value from a table ASFAIK, should be done in your REST service - in your case, if user wants ONLY  certain transaction, he's obliged to download all of them which may lead to some security issues. + You can checkout angular local storage and keep certain transaction in your browser cache.

Comment: My intent is to ultimately have the data broker control all the data flow and if it already has a transaction, it won't re-query the REST service. So I intend on doing a check later to see if it has it, and if not then it will query the server.

Right now however I'm just using the getTransaction method to edit one transaction of a list of transactions. This is all just a learning exercise so any tips are always appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good question. I know it's kind of confusing to work with RxJs at first but when you get the hang of it, it's quite powerful.

What you want can be achieved with `BehaviorSubject`.

Let's find out what `Subject` is and move onto `BehaviorSubject`

> Subject: is the equivalent to an EventEmitter, and the only way of multicasting a value or event to multiple Observers

For more info, take a look at [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html)

So, we know that `Subject` is like an `EventEmitter`. When someone subscribes to it, whenever you call `subject.next(value)`, every subscriber will get the new value. However, late subscribers (meaning subscribing to the `Subject` after `next` method is called) won't get the previous values. This is where `BehaviorSubject` will come into the scene.

It is just like `Subject`, but when a new subscriber subscribes to it, it'll emit the previous value. Let's use it in your code.

```
export class DataBrokerService {
    // do not expose your subject to other classes
    private _transactions$: BehaviorSubject<Transaction[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    // instead provide it as an observable
    public readonly transactions: Observable<Transaction[]> = this._transactions$.asObservable();

    needUpdate = true;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    // just return the observable
    getTransactions(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
        if (needUpdate) {
            this.updateTransactions();
        }
        return this.transactions;
    }

    // you can iterate over your transactions and filter them,
    // but DO NOT ever subscribe to it within a service. 
    // Otherwise, other classes won't be able to retrieve the value.
    getTransaction(id: number): Observable<Transaction> {
        return this.getTransactions().pipe(
            map(txns => txns.find(txn => txn.id === id))
        );
    }

    // when you need to update the transactions,
    // simply call this method
    updateTransactions() {
        this.http.get('transactions').subscribe(txns => {
            this.needUpdate = false;
            this._transactions$.next(txns);
        });
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. I think I understand more now. However, I am having trouble that the observable is not updating along with the Subject. This is shown in the following stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-demo-l5uyuq

Comment: It is because you change `this._items` from `BehaviorSubject` to `Observable` within `ngOnInit`. If you need to emit new value from `BehaviorSubject`, you just need to use `next(value)` method. Check this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-demo-bz1tic?file=app/app.component.ts