# BehaviorSubject can not receive value with subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, http, subscribe

### In My Angular Application

I made several attempts to get the values using a BehaviorSubject to know when the value was changed or received. I can not get the values before loading the component.

Through this link you can see what you are returning:

https://dev.moip.com.br/v1.5/reference#listar-planos

**data.service.ts:**

```
dataOnChanged: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});

getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(this.api_URL + 'plans/, this.httpOptions).subscribe((data: any) => {

            // the result is
            // data = {plans: Array(5)}

            this.dataOnChanged.next(data);
            resolve(data);
        },
            (response: any) => {
                reject(response.error);
            });
    });
}
```

**resolve.service.ts:**

```
constructor(
    private dataService: DataService, {
}

* Resolve
 * @param {ActivatedRouteSnapshot} route
 * @param {RouterStateSnapshot} state
 * @returns {Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any}
 */
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all([
            this.dataService.getData()
        ]).then(
            () => {
                resolve();
            },
            reject
        );
    });
}
```

**routes.module.ts:**

```
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent,
            resolve: {
                data: ResolveService,
            },
        },
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
constructor(
    public data: DataService,
) {

    this.dataService.dataOnChanged.subscribe((result: any) => {
        // no result
        debugger;
    });
```

The problem is that I can not load the data returned by HTTP GET before loading the component. I need to load the data before and show the screen.

Comment: So you're saying that `home.component` should not be visible until the GET has returned, is that right?

Comment: That's right, I need to load the data before ... To later display in HTML using angularinterpolation.

Comment: Have a look at `RouteResolvers`, sounds like what you're wanting https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Comment: Actually the component is being loaded only after receiving the data, but I can not get the data in the component using subscribe.

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand the problem now. Which `providers` array have you added the `DataService` to? Is it provided at the correct level to ensure the component and resolve service are using the same instance?

Comment: I wear @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
}) in all services.

Comment: Check this question out. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459815/how-to-organize-angular-data-service/50460681#50460681

Comment: I don't understand why you want to get the data before you load the component ? The service instance will be created when the component initializes.

Comment: I do not want to load before receiving the data because if I display the component before getting the data, will not appear the values on the screen ... just want to load the component when I get the values to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Your value will be display on the screen with observable pattern, I'm writing an answer and I maybe have a training project on my github I can show you (I'm still a beginner)

Comment: The moment I open the screen, it appears blank ... after a few seconds after running HTTP GET the value is returned and there it is displayed.

But I want it when you open the screen, the data is already loaded and ready to be displayed. So the use of resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `BehaviorSubject` is redundant over here instead you can access the resolved data using the `data` property of **[ActivatedRoute’s snapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)** object or subscribe to **[ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)** **`data`** Property which holds the static and resolved data of the current route
it's recommended to use **[Observables over promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable)**. By converting to a promise you will lose the ability to cancel a request and the ability to chain RxJS operators.

From **[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating)**

> 1. Rely on the router to call the resolver. Don't worry about all the
>      ways that the user could navigate away. That's the router's job.
>      Write this class and let the router take it from there.
> 2. The observable provided to the Router must complete. If the
>          observable does not complete, the navigation will not continue.

**data.service.ts:**

```
 getData():Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.api_URL + 'plans/, this.httpOptions);
            }
```

**resolve.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
   import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class resolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
      constructor(private service:Service) {}

      resolve() {
        return this.dataService.getdata();
      }
    }
```

**routes.module.ts:**

```
 {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent,
            resolve: {
                data: resolver,
            },
        },
```

**home.component.ts:,**

```
  constructor( private route:ActivatedRoute) {
                 this.route.data.subscribe(value=>{
                       console.log(value);
                       });}
```

**or**

```
 constructor( private route:ActivatedRoute) {
                 this.item=this.route.snapshot.data;
                    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
                     }
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmipb4)**

Comment: Hi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get the value will be to get it from the ActivatedRoute

In your component, if you inject the ActivatedRoute:

```
constructor(ars: ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(ars.snapshot.data.data) // This will log your value here
}
```

That way, you don't need the BehaviourSubject.

[Here is an example on StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-example-jc4bhz?file=app/resolver.service.ts)

When you visit the /about route, it will get a value on a 2second delay to demonstrate