# Subscribing to the same data in multiple smart components

Tags: angular

I an looking for recommendation how the code may be simplified if there is a need to to subscribe to the same data in multiple Angular smart components.

For example, this code is the same:

```
public item: Item | undefined;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.items$.subscribe(a => this.item = a);
}
```

Once I add unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy, the code duplication increases even more.

Is it possible to use simplify component somehow? Subscribe in root AppComponent or use Value Providers?

Pipes, in my understanding, are not an option in cases like handling button clicks/hammerjs gestures/code in ngOnChanges, when `this.item` is used inside a component, not template.

Answer (score 1):

To share an `Observable for multiple` `observers`, you need something like the **[share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html)**
operator.

**Example:**

```
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import {share} from 'rxjs/operators'

    export class dataService{
    public data$=Observable<Idata[]>
             constructor(http:HttpClient)
            {
               this.data$=this.http.get<Idata[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe(share());
             }
             public getPosts():Observable<Idata[]>
                {
                    return this.data$
                }}
```

> This operator is a specialization of `publish` which creates a
>   subscription when the number of observers goes from zero to one, then
>   shares that subscription with all subsequent observers until the
>   number of observers returns to zero, at which point the subscription
>   is disposed.

**[Refer this for more](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635)**

Since you want to  get resolved data before navigating to the new route you could use `Resolve` guard

*which  Performs route data retrieval before route activation.*
you can access the resolved data using the `data` property of **[ActivatedRoute’s snapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)** object or subscribe to **[ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)** **`data`** Property which holds the static and resolved data of the current route

**resolve.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
   import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class resolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
      constructor(private service:Service) {}

      resolve() {
        return this.dataService.getdata();
      }
    }
```

**routes.module.ts:**

```
 {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent,
            resolve: {
                data: resolver,
            },
        },
```

**.component.ts:,**

```
  constructor( private route:ActivatedRoute) {
                 this.route.data.subscribe(value=>{
                       console.log(value);
                       });}
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmipb4)**

**Refer**

   1. **[fetch-data-before-navigating](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating)**

2. **[Route Resolvers](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)**

Comment: And inject dataService into smart component to subscribe again? I don't see code reuse here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: well yeah, angular style guide says  *Logic may be reused by multiple components when placed within a service and exposed via a function.*  so inject the service and subscribe

Comment: even persisting the data in local storage would require you to inject it in the component in order to get the values

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631080/5695162) will give you a clearer picture

Comment: No no, my aim is to do something like we have with @Input, but on the higher level. Maybe AppComponent may be responsible for subscription and pass resolved data to router-outlet. Or maybe the value is resolved even on higher level and injected as value.

Comment: Ohh I see now I understand

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545563/5695162) and [this](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

Comment: Mate,I have updated my answer upvote and mark it if it is helpful :)